# Way to get word frequency from string?

Tags: c++, curl

Hey guys I have the following issue. I've been using C++ to scrape website using to find 5 most frequent words in outputHTML which is string. Currently I have following code. Any hint would be awesome.

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &htmlOutput);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    std::cout << htmlOutput << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hint:  use `std::map<std::string, unsigned int>`.

Comment: Hint: [Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_(statistics))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some hints for more awesomeness:

```
std::istringstream awsome_stream(web_text);
std::string word;
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> kewl_words;
while (awsome_stream >> word)
{
  kewl_words[word]++;
}
std::cout << "Occurances of 'div': " << kewl_words["div"] << "\n";
```